# What is the precedence among operators in XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath, operator-precedence, associativity

In this XPath expression: `//div[@id=”myID”]|p`, does the `//` operator get applied to both sides of the union operator? Or would this expression simply return all `div` elements in the document that have an `id` attribute value of `myID` and all `p` elements that are children of the context node?

Is there a reference for XPath operator binding and associativity?

Comment: both parts are executed as independed Xpathes. So you must write `//p`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## XPath Operator Order Precedence

The XPath [EBNF grammar](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xpath20-20101214/#id-grammar) implies the following precedence among operators (**lowest to highest**):

[image]

**Source**: [**XML Path Language (XPath) 2.0 (Second Edition)**](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xpath20-20101214/#id-precedence-order)

(See also: [XML Path Language (XPath) 3.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-xpath-30-20140408/#id-precedence-order))

---

Since `//` and `[]` are of higher precedence than `|` (union), your XPath expression

```
//div[@id=”myID”]|p
```

says

- select all `div` elements in the document with `@id` attribute value
  equal to `myID`,
- and select all `p` elements that are children of the context element,
- and take the union of those two sets of elements

to produce the final result (as you anticipated in your second interpretation).

Comment: Just to add to this, in XPath 1.0 there is no such table, but the precedence is defined implicitly by the grammar. For example the productions  `[21] AdditiveExpr ::= MultiplicativeExpr ( ("+" | "-") MultiplicativeExpr )*` and `[22] MultiplicativeExpr ::= UnionExpr ( ("*" | "div" | "idiv" | "mod") UnionExpr )*` tell us that the operands of "+" can contain a "*" or "div" operator, but not vice versa.

Comment: Should `@` be considered a highest-precedence operator? What about `::`?

Comment: Your question reduces to that of `::` because `@` is merely a shortcut for `attribute::`.  The table is only a summary of the normative precedence defined in the [EBNF grammar](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xpath20-20101214/#id-grammar), where you can find that `::` is part of `ForwardAxis` or `ReverseAxis`, which work their way up to `UnaryExpr`, which you see in the above table summarized as `unary`.  As such, consider `::` less as an [XPath operator](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/) and more as a defining syntactic part of an axis step, which plays with operators as a `UnaryExpr`.